# java stream pipeline to create map of lists

Tags: stream, collectors, groupingby

Its not real code, but an analogy to my exact scenario. Main concern here is the util stream pipeline.

Lets assume, I've following object model

```
    @Data
    class ItemRequest {
       String action;
       List<ItemId> itemIds;
    }
    @Data
    class ItemId{
       ItemType itemType;
       long itemKey;
    }
    @Getter 
    @AllArgsConstructor
    enum ItemType{

      String backingService;
      String description; 

      ITEM_TYPE_1("backingService1","type 1 description"),
      ITEM_TYPE_2("backingService1","type 2 description"),
      ITEM_TYPE_3("backingService2","type 3 description"),
      ITEM_TYPE_4("backingService2","type 4 description"),
      ITEM_TYPE_5("backingService2","type 5 description"),
      ITEM_TYPE_6("backingService3","type 6 description"),
      ITEM_TYPE_7("backingService3","type 7 description"),
     //   so on
    }
```

Now each ItemType has a different backend microservice.
My ItemType enum has getters to return backing service.
So I want to break down my ItemRequest by backing service.

I can easily do it in imperative way or running 2 stream pipeline.
But I want to use it in one stream pipeline

**For Example, in simple terms, my question is
How to combine following 2 steps I wrote  below into one pipeline**
.

```
Map<String,ItemRequest> breakItemRequestAsPerBackingService
 (ItemRequest originalItemRequest ){
    Map<String, List<ItemId>> collect
     = originalItemRequest
               .getItemIds()
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                     e -> e.getItemType().getBackingService()));



    return collect 
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(toMap(
             Map.Entry::getKey,
              e -> new ItemRequest(
                     originalItemRequest.getAction(), 
                     e.getValue())));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second operation

```java
collect.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> new ItemRequest(originalItemRequest.getAction(), e.getValue())));
```

is keeping the result key of the previous operation and only applying a function to the values. You can apply a function to the result of a previous `Collector` using [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)). To use it with `groupingBy` for the map values, you have to realize that `groupingBy(f)` is a short-hand for `groupingBy(f, toList())`, so `toList()` is the collector to combine with [`collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)).

```java
Map<String,ItemRequest>
    breakItemRequestAsPerBackingService(ItemRequest originalItemRequest) {

    return originalItemRequest.getItemIds().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getItemType().getBackingService(),
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                list -> new ItemRequest(originalItemRequest.getAction(), list))
        ));
}
```